# How to make sure autoincremented ID is unique in Google Sheets using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working with a script to add a new ID number (integer) in column A each time a new entry is made into a Google Sheet.

I currently have the script below installed, but it does not seem to be able to sense which numbers have already been used. Is there something I can add to my script which will ensure that it delivers only unique ID numbers?

I have already made sure that all the IDs are integers.

```
function myFunction() {
  var AUTOINC_COLUMN = 0;
  var HEADER_ROW_COUNT = 1;

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet   = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("sheetName");
  var rows        = worksheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var vals        = worksheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, rows+1, 2);

  for (var row = HEADER_ROW_COUNT; row < vals.length; row++) {
    try {
      var id = vals[row][AUTOINC_COLUMN];
      Logger.log(id);Logger.log((""+id).length ===0);
      if ((""+id).length === 0) {
        worksheet.getRange(row+1, AUTOINC_COLUMN+1).setValue(row);
      }
    } catch(ex) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did the provided answers solve your problem? If not, can you specify please what you mean by unique ID? Is the ID supposed to be unique within AUTOINC_COLUMN in your worksheet, within the whole worksheet, within all sheets in a spreadsheet, or within all spreadsheets on your drive?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function uniqueId() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet177");
  var idA=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];}).sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
  Logger.log(idA[0]+1);
  return idA[0]+1;
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for this suggestion! It doesn't seem to have worked. 

I may have not implemented properly, though - I replaced the old code with the one you suggested. Then I ran it, and it seems to have done nothing at all.

I'd appreciate your help in solving this!

Comment: This is just returning the new id.  You probably need to insert it where you wish and you need to change the sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

This solution saves the autoincrement ID in a document property store.  When a row is edited, it checks if an ID exists, and if not it looks in the property store for the next ID.  If the property in uninitialized, it reads the whole sheet and looks for the largest ID number.

```js
function onEdit(edit) {
  var sheet = edit.range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  if (sheetName !== "sheetName") {
    return;
  }
  var idCell = sheet.getRange(edit.range.getRow(), 1);
  if (idCell.getValue() !== "") {
    return;
  }
  var props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var nextID = +props.getProperty(sheetName + "id");
  if (nextID === null) {
    nextID = setIdProperty(sheet);
  }
  idCell.setValue(nextID);
  props.setProperty(sheetName + "id", nextID + 1);
}

// initializes the stored "id" property
function setIdProperty(sheet) {
  var AUTOINC_COLUMN = 0;
  var max = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().reduce(function(max, row) {
    return +row[AUTOINC_COLUMN] > max ? +row[AUTOINC_COLUMN] : max;
  }, 0);
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty(sheet.getName() + "id", max + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for this, dwmorrin! I am constantly manipulating the sheet, so I have opted not to use the second script you recommended. The first one looks promising - the only issue I'm finding is that it's throwing an error every time it comes across a lack of adherence to my data validation rules in other (unrelated) columns. Do you know of a tweak that would focus the script to only Column A?

Comment: @RCWoodmass I was about to delete my answer actually because I think I misunderstood and had it in my head you just need to apply this function once rather than constantly. I'll leave it up since it is useful to you and edit it after thinking some more on it.

Comment: Thank you! I added more context on my initial post as well.